# Setting up Form Controls in Kentico 13

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc, kentico-13

I have a website in Kentico 12 portal engine and I have few custom form controls created in Kentico 12.

I am creating a new website in Kentico 13 and it doesn't have "Form Controls" module in the Kentico admin panel. Please review the screenshot below:

[image]

Can you please let me know is it possible to add form control in Kentico 13 at admin side or we need to create a custom "Form component" in Kentico 13?

Also can you please let me know if there is a way to convert the "Form control" in Kentico 12 portal engine to an equivalent "Form component" in K13 or need to create from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

"Form Controls" as you were used to in version 12 no longer exist.  Technically speaking the form control is now only available for the Admin Interface.  You can access the Admin UI Form Controls under the following Kentico menu item:

Development > Administration Interface > Form controls